# Warning: touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied

Tags: php, touch

I am writing the session to a temporary file as follows:

```
if ($_SESSION['user_login_status'] == 1)
        {
        touch("tmp/access-" . session_id()); 
        }
```

I have the following permissions set on tmp just to test it is working (I will modify permissions to be more restrictive as I test):

```
drwxrwxrwx+
```

I receive the following error:

```
Warning: touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied
```

Any thoughts? Everything I have googled thus far says check the permissions (done) or is related to a wordpress error which I am not running. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same error message show up (but a different code snippet). What solved it for me was to change the owner for the file, i.e. `chown uname:uname filename`.

Comment: "What solved it for me was to change the owner for the file" - so what was the owner originally and what did you change it to?

Comment: From foggy memory, I think the previous owner was a system account such as `root` and I changed it to my own account (my system was Ubuntu 16.04)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the permissions on the directory are not the problem, rather the "access-" . session_id() seems to already exist and it's permissions are so that the PHP process can't change it's Utime. Check if the file "access-" . session_id() exist, if so remove it and run the script. If you do not receive an error check if the file "access-" . session_id() was created and what it's permissions are. If they are not correct try to chmod the file directly after creating it with touch.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the error and just removed the underlying files and the error went away...

Comment: This worked for me after calling `chmod o+w`  on the directory first.