# touch(): Utime failed: No such file or directory error Excel::download() in laravel using maatwebsite\Excel

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I get the error

> "touch(): Utime failed: No such file or directory" in 
>   vendor\maatwebsite\excel\src\Files\LocalTemporaryFile.php

When i try to download :

```
return Excel::download($export, 'users'.'_log.xlsx');
```

It works perfectly on my computer but after deploying i get the above error.

**vendor\maatwebsite\excel\src\Files\LocalTemporaryFile.php**

```
<?php

namespace Maatwebsite\Excel\Files;

class LocalTemporaryFile extends TemporaryFile
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $filePath;

    /**
     * @param string $filePath
     */
    public function __construct(string $filePath)
    {
        touch($filePath);

        $this->filePath = realpath($filePath);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22568289/warning-touch-utime-failed-permission-denied). It might be worth look at: https://processwire.com/talk/topic/14825-error-on-new-server-warning-touch-utime-failed/ as well.

Comment: Probably permissions related, check that you have write permissions on that file.

Comment: I have checked for permission and its all in place.

Comment: Another challenge is that i don't know the directory the error is referencing

Comment: It was indeed a permission problem, i used dd() to print the directory in question and then applied the necessary permission, thanks.

Comment: what permission was that?